# What is the best practice to implement update profile picture in PHP Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to allow my user to update their profile photo and I'm wondering what is the best practice to implement something like that in Laravel.

Here is my user **profile picture**. When they hover on it, they will have an option to update their photo.

[image]

When the user click on the camera logo or the update profile picture, I want to bring this file upload windows.

[image]

Unfortunate, I could get it to do that.

---

I've tried

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update_profile_picture', $user->id ),'method' => 'PUT')) !!}

<a class="pmop-edit">
  <i class="md md-camera-alt"></i>
  <span class="hidden-xs">Update Profile Picture</span>
</a>

{!! Form::hidden('$id', $user->id)!!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

I'm not sure what to do next at the moment. A little push will be much appreciated.

Can someone please shed some light on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this

**HTML**

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update_profile_picture', $user->id ),'method' => 'PUT')) !!}

<a class="pmop-edit" >
<span id="file-upload" >
  <i class="md md-camera-alt"></i>
  <span class="hidden-xs">Update Profile Picture</span>
</span>
  <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
    <input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload" onchange="sub(this)" />
  </div>
</a>

{!! Form::hidden('$id', $user->id)!!}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

---

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#file-upload").on("click", getFile);
    $("#upfile").on("change", sub);

    function getFile() {
        document.getElementById("upfile").click();
    }

    function sub(obj) {
        var file = obj.value;
        var fileName = file.split("\\");
        document.getElementById("file-upload").innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length - 1];
        document.myForm.submit();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Hope this help someone like me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is best practice but you could try using Laravels Form builder function

```
{!! Form::file('image', null) !!}
```

You would also need to add the following to your Form::open array `'files' => true`

This page may help also [Processing File Uploads With Laravel 5](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/04/08/processing-file-uploads-with-laravel-5/)

I haven't tested the code but I have done something similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm aware about the form::file in Laravel already. Thanks for it though.